# Android load pictures from firestorage with Glide

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebaseui

I load user's picture from firestorage with this code but it has some issues like the pics blink when scroll, reload every time I open the app and sometimes the pics take a long time to load I try to add                                         .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
because it takes too long to change the picture, I need help to load it faster and make it not to blink

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/"+ theUID);
Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .asBitmap()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(pic) {
            @Override
            protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(),
                        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, 150, 150, false));
                drawable.setCircular(true);
                pic.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }
        });
```